# If using all scalar values, you must pass an index shell returned 1

Tags: python, pandas

my original dataframe is like this

```
11S 420  3.65%
11N 580  0.19%
12S 450  6.13%
```

I want to creat new dataframe filter1 filter2 filter3 like the original dataframe and if the index number between 1 and 8 I append to the filter1  dataframe  if  the index nubmer between 9 and 16 I append to the filter2

```
i_r = g_e[['intrude', '8-11to10-17']]
filter1 = pd.DataFrame({"intrude":"","8-11to10-7":""})
filter2 = pd.DataFrame({"intrude":"","8-11to10-7":""})
filter3 = pd.DataFrame({"intrude":"","8-11to10-7":""})

for index1, row1 in i_r.iterrows():
    number = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}', row1.name)
    if pd.to_numeric(number) <= 8 :
         filter1.append(index1)
    if pd.to_numeric(number) <= 16:
         filter2.append(index1)
    if pd.to_numeric(number) <= 28:
         filter3.append(index1)
```

Comment: what is your question? (and: the last 2 `if`s should probably be `elif`s)

Comment: Yes elif is a good idea but  three if also  works well , the important  is my create empty dataframe and append  according row is likely not corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try and use vectorised operations where possible. In this instance, there's no need to iterate rows. Here's an example which extracts integers to a series; and then applies filters using [`pd.Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df = i_r.copy()
df['index'] = df.index.str[:-1].astype(int)

df1 = df.loc[df['index'] <= 8]
df2 = df.loc[df['index'].between(9, 16)]
df3 = df.loc[df['index'].between(17, 28)]

print(df2)

     intrude 8-11to10-17  index
11S      420       3.65%     11
11N      580       0.19%     11
12S      450       6.13%     12
```

Comment: thank a lot it works well  I from your code see the beautiful of python.